# How to generate a weblogo image that takes into account sequence frequencies?

Tags: sequence-alignment

I have a large aligned amino acid sequences file (fasta file) from next generation sequencing data. 
The unique sequences have been aligned but these all have certain read counts (frequencies associated with them).

I would like to generate a weblogo image that has the true probability of amino acids at each position. 
Is there a way to input frequencies/read counts with the aligned files of sequences using weblogo?
For example, in the title of the fasta file or as a csv/tsv file?

So that when generating the weblogo image it takes into account the abundances of each sequence?

Comment: can't you just duplicate the sequences to match the original frequencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the unique sequences. The whole point of sequence logos is that the height of the letter represents its frequency at a given position. You remove this information when you make your sequences unique. So, while it makes sense to use unique sequences when aligning, you shouldn't when building your logo.

Generate a simple mapping file (`counts`) with the number of times each sequence was found:

```
seq1 3
seq2 10
seq3 2
```

Then, given an aligned protein fasta file (`foo.aln`) like this:

```
>seq1
MEEPQS---DPSVEPP-LSQETFSDLWKLCFLPENNVLSPLPSQAM-DDL
>seq2
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq3
MEEPCS---DPSVEPPQLSQETFSDLRKL--LPENNFLSPLPSQAMCDDL
```

You can simply repeat the sequences as needed (see my answer [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2651/298) for the `FastaToTbl` and `TblToFasta` commands):

```
$ awk '
        (NR==FNR){
            count[$1]=$2; 
            next
        } 
        {
            for(k=1;k<=count[$1];k++){
                print $1"."k"\t"$2
            }
        }' counts <(FastaToTbl foo.aln) | TblToFasta
>seq1.1 
MEEPQS---DPSVEPP-LSQETFSDLWKLCFLPENNVLSPLPSQAM-DDL
>seq1.2 
MEEPQS---DPSVEPP-LSQETFSDLWKLCFLPENNVLSPLPSQAM-DDL
>seq1.3 
MEEPQS---DPSVEPP-LSQETFSDLWKLCFLPENNVLSPLPSQAM-DDL
>seq2.1 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.2 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.3 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.4 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.5 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.6 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.7 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.8 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.9 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq2.10 
MEEPQSCFGDPSVEPPPLSQETFKDLWKL--LCENNVLS---SQAM-DDL
>seq3.1 
MEEPCS---DPSVEPPQLSQETFSDLRKL--LPENNFLSPLPSQAMCDDL
>seq3.2 
MEEPCS---DPSVEPPQLSQETFSDLRKL--LPENNFLSPLPSQAMCDDL
```

Note that the above assumes your shell supports the `<(command)` syntax for [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Bash, the default shell on most Linux and macOSX installations does, but if you are using a shell that doesn't, you might need to run `FastaToTbl foo.aln > foo.tbl` first, and then use `foo.tbl` as input.

Comment: That's great thanks. I have my tabular file containing the read counts and my aligned fasta file although I am only familar with using R not c++. Can this script be adapted/used in R?

Comment: That isn't C++! It's just a shell command using [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Just copy/paste the command above directly into a *nix terminal. You will have to also take the two scripts from the other answer I link to.

Comment: Ok sorry I did not recognise this. I have my two files: sequence.tbl (ID with aligned sequences already converted to tabular form) and counts.tbl (ID with read counts). I set up the directory to these files and entered your code into my ubuntu terminal and nothing happens. I doesn't print the output or come up with any errors? Do I need to add a command to print into an output tabular file?

Comment: I copy/paste the exact command above just changing the last line to, 
        }' counts.tbl < sequence.tbl

Comment: @clfrankling yeah, that's a big change :) The `<` is wrong. If you already have them in tbl format, you need the command to end with `}' counts.tbl  sequence.tbl`.  Ping me (`@terdon`) in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58858/bioinformatics) if you need more help. It will be easier to debug that way