# Filtering fasta files by ID

Tags: python, fasta

I have this code to filter some IDs from a fasta file:

```
for line in file_open:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if '16S' in line:
        header=line
        header=header[0] + header[1:]
        seq=file_open.readline()
        seq=seq.strip()
        print(header + '\n'  + seq)
```

however, this code doesn't get me all content of each ID sequence. I get this result:

```
>ID1
AGTTTTGCCGAATTCCTTTAGGATTTTGTGAGGAACATTGTGTTAAATGTATTTATAGTTCTACTAATTC
```

When I should get this:

```
>ID1
AGTTTTGCCGAATTCCTTTAGGATTTTGTGAGGAACATTGTGTTAAATGTATTTATAGTTCTACTAATTC
TGCGAAGGTAGCATAATCATTAGCCTTTTGATTTGAGGCTGGAATGAATGGTTTGACGAGAGATGGTCTG
GGGCCGTGGTATACTGACCATGCGAAGGTAGCATAATCATTAGCCTCTTGATTTGAGGCTGGAATGAATG
GGGCCGTGGTATAC
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove/delete sequences by ID from multifasta](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/14421/29)

Comment: Well, the code you wrote prints the seq on a single line (and without any newline afterwards), are you sure that's not the only problem?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the question is more about writing the fasta file well formated.

Comment: @KamilSJaron No, the question isn’t about formatting. Check the output in the question again. It isn’t all on one line, it’s *truncated* (as in, only the first line is read and written, subsequent lines are omitted).

Comment: I thought that the truncated line could be due to copypasting. Now I see, it's not about the formatting of output, but expected formatting of the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're assuming 2-line FASTA format, but the sequence can (and typically does) span multiple lines. You can use [Biopython](https://biopython.org/) to build a simple parser:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse("file_name.fa", "fasta"):
    if "16S" in record.description:
        print(record.format("fasta"))
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you so much