# how to merge two fasta based on full fasta header and remove the duplicate

Tags: fasta, text-processing

I am wondering if anyone can help to merge two fasta file based on the full header as initially gene ID may be similar in some of the sequences and to remove the duplicate entry based on full fasta header

I do have two multifasta file:

file1:

```
>AOIT01000069.1:1403-2242 Haloterrigena limicola JCM 13563 contig_69, whole genome shotgun sequence
ATGAGTAACGATACGGTAGCTGGTGACCGCGACCCCGAGGAGGCCCGTGAGATGGTGCGCGAACGCTACG
GGACGATCGCTTCGGACGGTCAGGACTGCTGTGGCGATGTCGGCATCGATGTCACCGACGACGGTGGGTG

>LOPV01000533.1:1144-1992 Haloferax sp. SB29 contig_613, whole genome shotgun sequence
ATGAGTGACGACACCCAGACTGGCACGACAGCCGACGACCGCGATCCAGAGGCGACTCGCCAGTTGGTAC
GGGAACGCTACGCCGGAATCGCATCGAGCGACCAGGGCTGTTGTAGCGACGTCGGCCTCGATGTCACGGG


>AOLJ01000027.1:50569-51417 Haloferax gibbonsii ATCC 33959 contig_27, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGAAGGTCGGTTTCCGGGCTTCGATGGTGGCCGACACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCCTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCAGTACTCTCGTCCTTGGGTGCAATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCAGCGC
```

file2:

```
>AOLJ01000027.1:50569-51417 Haloferax gibbonsii ATCC 33959 contig_27, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGAAGGTCGGTTTCCGGGCTTCGATGGTGGCCGACACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCCTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCAGTACTCTCGTCCTTGGGTGCAATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCAGCGC


>AM774418.1:280304-281149 Halobacterium salinarum R1 plasmid PHS3 complete genome
ATGAGTAATGACAACGAGACGATGGTCGCCGATCGCGATCCCGAGGAGACTCGCGAGATGGTGCGGGAAC
GCTACGCGGGAATCGCGACGAGCGGCCAGGACTGCTGTGGTGACGTCGGTTTGGATGTCTCTGGCGACGG

>AOJK01000067.1:53467-54312 Halorubrum californiensis DSM 19288 contig_67, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGCGGGCTGGTTTTCGGGCTTCGATGGTAGCGGAAACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCGTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCGGTGCTCTCGTCCTTCGGCGCGATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCCGCCT
```

Expected output:

```
>AOIT01000069.1:1403-2242 Haloterrigena limicola JCM 13563 contig_69, whole genome shotgun sequence
ATGAGTAACGATACGGTAGCTGGTGACCGCGACCCCGAGGAGGCCCGTGAGATGGTGCGCGAACGCTACG
GGACGATCGCTTCGGACGGTCAGGACTGCTGTGGCGATGTCGGCATCGATGTCACCGACGACGGTGGGTG

>LOPV01000533.1:1144-1992 Haloferax sp. SB29 contig_613, whole genome shotgun sequence
ATGAGTGACGACACCCAGACTGGCACGACAGCCGACGACCGCGATCCAGAGGCGACTCGCCAGTTGGTAC
GGGAACGCTACGCCGGAATCGCATCGAGCGACCAGGGCTGTTGTAGCGACGTCGGCCTCGATGTCACGGG

>AOLJ01000027.1:50569-51417 Haloferax gibbonsii ATCC 33959 contig_27, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGAAGGTCGGTTTCCGGGCTTCGATGGTGGCCGACACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCCTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCAGTACTCTCGTCCTTGGGTGCAATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCAGCGC

>AM774418.1:280304-281149 Halobacterium salinarum R1 plasmid PHS3 complete genome
ATGAGTAATGACAACGAGACGATGGTCGCCGATCGCGATCCCGAGGAGACTCGCGAGATGGTGCGGGAAC
GCTACGCGGGAATCGCGACGAGCGGCCAGGACTGCTGTGGTGACGTCGGTTTGGATGTCTCTGGCGACGG

>AOJK01000067.1:53467-54312 Halorubrum californiensis DSM 19288 contig_67, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGCGGGCTGGTTTTCGGGCTTCGATGGTAGCGGAAACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCGTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCGGTGCTCTCGTCCTTCGGCGCGATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCCGCCT
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) an example of your input files including "matching" and "non-matching" sequences and ii) the output you would expect from those input files.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Will sequences with the same header be identical? If so, why not extract all unique sequences directly instead of trying to find identical headers?

Comment: yes, same header have identical sequences, it will be great to extract unique sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FastaToTbl` and `TblToFasta` scripts I have posted [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2651/298) for this:

```
FastaToTbl file1.fa file2.fa | sort | uniq | TblToFasta > merged.fa
```

If you run this on your example, you will get:

```
$ FastaToTbl file1.fa file2.fa | sort | uniq | TblToFasta > merged.fa
$ cat merged.fa 
>AM774418.1:280304-281149 Halobacterium salinarum R1 plasmid PHS3 complete genome 
ATGAGTAATGACAACGAGACGATGGTCGCCGATCGCGATCCCGAGGAGACTCGCGAGATG
GTGCGGGAACGCTACGCGGGAATCGCGACGAGCGGCCAGGACTGCTGTGGTGACGTCGGT
TTGGATGTCTCTGGCGACGG
>AOIT01000069.1:1403-2242 Haloterrigena limicola JCM 13563 contig_69, whole genome shotgun sequence 
ATGAGTAACGATACGGTAGCTGGTGACCGCGACCCCGAGGAGGCCCGTGAGATGGTGCGC
GAACGCTACGGGACGATCGCTTCGGACGGTCAGGACTGCTGTGGCGATGTCGGCATCGAT
GTCACCGACGACGGTGGGTG
>AOJK01000067.1:53467-54312 Halorubrum californiensis DSM 19288 contig_67, whole genome shotgun sequence 
TCAGTCGTCGCGGGCTGGTTTTCGGGCTTCGATGGTAGCGGAAACGAGGTACTCGCCGAG
GTCGCGGTCGGCGTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCGGTGCTCTCGTCCTTCGGCGCGATCTC
GACCGCCTCGAAGCCCGCCT
>AOLJ01000027.1:50569-51417 Haloferax gibbonsii ATCC 33959 contig_27, whole genome shotgun sequence 
TCAGTCGTCGAAGGTCGGTTTCCGGGCTTCGATGGTGGCCGACACGAGGTACTCGCCGAG
GTCGCGGTCGGCCTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCAGTACTCTCGTCCTTGGGTGCAATCTC
GACCGCCTCGAAGCCAGCGC
>LOPV01000533.1:1144-1992 Haloferax sp. SB29 contig_613, whole genome shotgun sequence 
ATGAGTGACGACACCCAGACTGGCACGACAGCCGACGACCGCGATCCAGAGGCGACTCGC
CAGTTGGTACGGGAACGCTACGCCGGAATCGCATCGAGCGACCAGGGCTGTTGTAGCGAC
GTCGGCCTCGATGTCACGGG
```

This will remove any cases where both the header and the sequence are identical. If you instead want to do this based on the header only, not taking the sequences into account, you can just process both files and only print sequences from the 2nd if their ID line hasn't been seen before. For example, with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ 
        if(NR==FNR){ 
            if(/^>/){seen[$0]++;} 
            print
        }
        else{ 
            if(/^>/){ skip=seen[$0] } 
            if(!skip){ print }
        }
       }' file1.fa file2.fa 
>AOIT01000069.1:1403-2242 Haloterrigena limicola JCM 13563 contig_69, whole genome shotgun sequence
ATGAGTAACGATACGGTAGCTGGTGACCGCGACCCCGAGGAGGCCCGTGAGATGGTGCGCGAACGCTACG
GGACGATCGCTTCGGACGGTCAGGACTGCTGTGGCGATGTCGGCATCGATGTCACCGACGACGGTGGGTG

>LOPV01000533.1:1144-1992 Haloferax sp. SB29 contig_613, whole genome shotgun sequence
ATGAGTGACGACACCCAGACTGGCACGACAGCCGACGACCGCGATCCAGAGGCGACTCGCCAGTTGGTAC
GGGAACGCTACGCCGGAATCGCATCGAGCGACCAGGGCTGTTGTAGCGACGTCGGCCTCGATGTCACGGG


>AOLJ01000027.1:50569-51417 Haloferax gibbonsii ATCC 33959 contig_27, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGAAGGTCGGTTTCCGGGCTTCGATGGTGGCCGACACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCCTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCAGTACTCTCGTCCTTGGGTGCAATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCAGCGC
>AM774418.1:280304-281149 Halobacterium salinarum R1 plasmid PHS3 complete genome
ATGAGTAATGACAACGAGACGATGGTCGCCGATCGCGATCCCGAGGAGACTCGCGAGATGGTGCGGGAAC
GCTACGCGGGAATCGCGACGAGCGGCCAGGACTGCTGTGGTGACGTCGGTTTGGATGTCTCTGGCGACGG

>AOJK01000067.1:53467-54312 Halorubrum californiensis DSM 19288 contig_67, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCAGTCGTCGCGGGCTGGTTTTCGGGCTTCGATGGTAGCGGAAACGAGGTACTCGCCGAGGTCGCGGTCG
GCGTCCCAGTCGCTGATGAACTCGGTGCTCTCGTCCTTCGGCGCGATCTCGACCGCCTCGAAGCCCGCCT
```

Comment: it will be great to remove identical sequences as well based nucleotide sequence. but it is showing error: $ chmod +x FastaToTbl 
$ chmod +x TblToFasta 
$FastaToTbl file1.fasta file2.fasta | sort | uniq | TblToFasta > merged.fa
bash: FastaToTbl: command not found...
bash: TblToFasta: command not found...

Comment: @Dr.Yogesh yes, that's because you didn't put the scripts in a directory that's in your `PATH`. If you have them in the current directory, use `./FastaToTbl file1.fa file2.fa | sort | uniq | ./TblToFasta > merged.fa`

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to copy the script again!

Comment: Thanks, it is working perfectly now, it was sensitive to extra space!