# How to remove duplicates from a fasta file using python

Tags: fasta, python

I am using the following command:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 


fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
if len(myfile.seq) > 250:
    gene_id = myfile.id
    mylist = re.match(r"H149xcV_[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+_[^\W_])_[^\W_]+", gene_id)
    print (">"+mylist.group(1))
```

And this is providing me with duplicates of the same gene:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
```

How can I reformat my command so that I only receive unique gene id's:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2
```

Comment: Why do you need to use python for this?

Comment: I am using `nano` within commandline to write my python command. @RamRS

Comment: I'm asking **why**, not **how**. There are command line tools that de-dup fasta, so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @RamRS The only command-line tools that I am aware of are `sort`|`uniq` but I am not sure as to how I would use it? I must apologize, I am kind of new to bioinformatics, so I am still getting the hang of it. I know I can output my python into another file, but is there a way to obtain the unique id's afterwards? Thanks!

Comment: You can use  `seqkit rmdup` instead reinvent the wheel. https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#rmdup

Comment: @zorbax I think that would be a good answer...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use Python for this, myself. Instead you can use the FastaToTbl and TblToFasta scripts [I have posted before](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2651/298), and pipe to standard *nix utilities:

```
FastaToTbl file.fa | sort -u | TblToFasta > file.uniq.fa
```

Or, if you don't have GNU `sort`:

```
FastaToTbl file.fa | sort | uniq | TblToFasta > file.uniq.fa
```

Alternatively, you can also do something like this:

```
awk -v RS='>' -v ORS='>' '++a[$0]==1' file.fa | sed 's/>$//'
```

For example, given this input file:

```
$ cat file.fa
>seq1
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
>seq2
ATGGCGCGCTTAGGAGCGCTAGGACT
>seq2
ATGGCGCGCTTAGGAGCGCTAGGACT
>seq1
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
>seq1
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
```

You can do:

```
$ awk -v RS='>' -v ORS='>' '++a[$0]==1' file.fa | sed 's/>$//'
>seq1
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
ACTTCGCAGAGGCTTCGGAGAGA
>seq2
ATGGCGCGCTTAGGAGCGCTAGGACT
```

Both of the above approaches have the advantage of not needing to store the entire file in memory.

Comment: There is also an application at UCSC utilities that converts Fasta to Tab separated file. It's called `faToTab` and can be downloaded from http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/

Answer (score 1):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 

unique = []
fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
    if len(myfile) > 250:
        gene_id = myfile.id
        if gene.id not in unique:
            unique.append(gene.id)
            mylist = re.match(r"H149xcV_[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+_[^\W_])_[^\W_]+", gene_id)
            print (">"+mylist.group(1))
```

Comment: Yeah, I would do something along these lines too. Though, I would use a set or dict insead of list if the fasta file is big...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps itertools might be an option? From the itertools page / moreitertools project
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

```py
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `dict` so that the lookup time is constant. If you are creating an array with all the unique gene IDs, then checking if a gene is in that array, your runtime is O(N<sup>2</sup>). When you create an entry in the `dict`, the time to access is constant, and if the entry is already present, it will just overwrite it. Something like this should do it for you:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
    
genes = {}
fasta_file = sys.argv[1]
for entry in SeqIO.parse( fasta_file, "fasta" ):
    genes[ entry.id ] = entry.seq
```

Then you can write a new, unique fasta file:

```
with open('unique_genes.fasta', 'w') as out:
    for key,value in genes.items():
        out.write( '>%s\n%s\n'%(key,value) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't well formatted, for example list is used as a variable name where it should be reserved as a keyword...

```
print (">"+list.group(1))
```

However, the answer you're after is going to be something like:

```
print (">"+set(name_of_list.group(1)))
```

Anytime you want to get the unique elements of a list, just wrap it in set()

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code. It doesn't only remove repeated sequences but similar sequences (with a quite simplistic approach).
I use it just sporadically and I guess it can be largely depurated. Remove the debug prints if these annoy you.

```
import sys
import requests 
import shlex, subprocess
import random
from Bio import SeqIO
import editdistance

if len(sys.argv)<3:
    print("Uso: "+sys.argv[0]+" input_fasta output_fasta")
    sys.exit(0)

savefile = sys.argv[2]
content_file = sys.argv[1]

class Sequence:
    id=""
    sequence=""

def are_similar(seq1, seq2):
    l1 = len(seq1.sequence)
    l2 = len(seq2.sequence)
    if abs(l1-l2) < l1/40:
        d = editdistance.eval(seq1.sequence[0:250], seq2.sequence[0:250])
        #d = editdistance.eval(seq1.sequence, seq2.sequence)
        print(seq1.id+" "+seq2.id+" -> "+str(d))
        #if d < l1/20:
        if d < 50:
            return True
    return False

def find_repeats(sequences, seq, repeated):
    b=False
    for seq2 in sequences:
        if(b and not seq2.id in repeated):
            if are_similar(seq, seq2):
                repeated.add(seq2.id)        
        if seq2.id==seq.id:
            b=True

sequences=[]

res=""

for record in SeqIO.parse(content_file, "fasta"):
    seq=Sequence()
    seq.id=record.id
    seq.sequence=record.seq
    sequences.append(seq)

repeated_sequences=set()
for seq in sequences:
    find_repeats(sequences, seq, repeated_sequences)

print(repeated_sequences)

def mySortFunc(e):
    return len(e.sequence)

sequences.sort(key=mySortFunc)

for seq in sequences:
    b= seq.id in repeated_sequences
    if not b:
        res+=">"+seq.id+"\n"
        res+=str(seq.sequence)+"\n"

output_file = open(savefile, "w")

output_file.write(res)

output_file.close()
```

EDIT: I see that's not exactly what OP is asking ...